# Why aren't all bond lengths equal in cyclobutadiene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond

[image]

even when there is a possibility of conjugation why aren't bond lengths equal?

Comment: Could you cite where you found that the bond lengths are not equal?

Comment: Heard of anti aromaticity  it destabilizes a cyclic compound so to prevent it no conjugation

Comment: Your title does not match your question. All ***double*** bonds are equal all right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resonance structure of cyclobutadiene?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24391/resonance-structure-of-cyclobutadiene)

Answer (score 4):

Anti-aromatic compounds have no delocalization of electrons hence no resonance. To check aromatic character we use huckel's rule of (4n+2)π e- present in a conjugated closed loop. An anti aromatic compound would have only 4nπ electrons which is the case with above mentioned compound . Hence the bond lengths are different.
[image][image]