Why do these two molecules have the same InChI?
I recently found two different molecules, which have exactly the same InChI:
1,2-dimethylcyclobuta-1,3-diene and 1,4-dimethylcyclobuta-1,3-diene both have InChI=1S/C6H8/c1-5-3-4-6(5)2/h3-4H,1-2H3 and InChIKey=QNZUSULCBOVZRK-UHFFFAOYSA-N.
Why is this the case? Shouldn’t there be a way to differentiate these two molecules?


Same issue with other annulenes: 1,2-dimethylcycloocta-1,3,5,7-tetraene vs 1,8-dimethylcycloocta-1,3,5,7-tetraene, both have InChI=1S/C10H12/c1-9-7-5-3-4-6-8-10(9)2/h3-8H,1-2H3/b4-3-,5-3-,6-4-,7-5-,8-6-,9-7-,10-8-,10-9-.


I have little knowledge about orbitals and aromaticity and such, but I asked my chemistry teacher and they said these are two very different molecules and are not tautomers since cyclobutadiene is antiaromatic.

Well, this feels like missing the point. I mean it would be OK point of starting to ponder the implication's of cyclobutadiene's geometry, but you didn't go far enough and the title isn't informative.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18557/is-cyclobutadiene-antiaromatic https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/127937/why-arent-all-bonds-in-cyclobutadiene-not-equal

I could fix this pretty easily, though, if you don't mind a bit bigger edit.

Well, you have a carbon layer, and you have a hydrogen layer. Are the different? Keep in mind that InChI isn't capable of encoding bond length or order. And these two molecules really only exist as a graph on a proverbial piece of paper…

These are two views of the same molecule.

And even if these weren't two resonance structures of the same molecule, but were distinct tautomers, they mights still have the same InChI. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34563/pubchem-inchi-smiles-and-uniqueness

So, you are saying these two molecules are tautomers of eachother/the same molecule? I have little knowledge about this, but I asked my chemistry teacher and they said these are two very different molecules and are not tautomers since cyclobutadiene is antiaromatic.

A rough-and-ready rule that usually works for comparing two structures is, "if no nuclei including H change locations, and if all the same nuclei are connected to each other" then the two structures are different resonance structures of the same molecule.  This rule probably doesn't work well for anti-aromatic conjugated systems like the cyclooctatetraene molecules you've found.  Read the question I linked before.  It's not clear (to me at least) that InChI is designed to differentiate the two structures you've shown.
