# Are pi electrons in 1,3 cyclobutadiene delocalised?

Tags: aromatic-compounds

The original question in my test was whether all bonds in the aforementioned molecule are of same length. According to the solution booklet, it is not because pi electrons are not delocalised due to anti-aromatic character.

This seems a bit weird...

Comment: What's weird about it? Indeed, there is no aromaticity here, hence different bond length.

Comment: It's weird because resonance takes place regardless of the aromatic or anti-aromatic character of a molecule. Hence shouldn't the bond order be 1.5 for every C-C bond??

Comment: If you look at them long enough, **yes**. If you take a flash photo (figuratively speaking), then **yes** for aromatic compounds, but **no** for antiaromatic, like this one.

Comment: May find the answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18557/is-cyclobutadiene-antiaromatic).