# Is cyclobut‐3‐ene‐1,2‐diide aromatic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, aromaticity

I think cyclobut‐3‐ene‐1,2‐diide is non-aromatic since there are two sp<sup>3</sup> carbons (carrying negative charge), but my source says it is aromatic. Why?

[image: cyclobut‐3‐ene‐1,2‐diide]

Comment: https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2017/03/03/is-this-molecule-aromatic-some-practice-problems/

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/18566/9961

Comment: simplified answer-the carbons are not sp3 because lone pairs delocalized by resonance are not counted in the hybridization of the atom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because a carbon atom is negatively charged and has a lone pair, it need not be $sp^3$ hybridized. The lone pair could be on a $\pi$-bonding $p$ orbital with the atom hybridized $sp^2$. If you allow for this possibility, you find that the given ion can satisfy the $4n+2$ rule for aromaticity, which the text apparently is claiming.

Whether the ion is actually a stable aromatic species is more complicated. Formation of a highly strained ring, the high charge density, and a relatively low amount of resonance stabilization for four-member aromatic rings all work against forming a strongly stabilized ring (the cyclopropenyl cation is also highly strained, but it has less charge density and greater resonance stabilization). Known cyclobutadiene-dianion compounds are stabilized by using substituents that allow some dispersion of the charge and closely associating the counterions above or below the ring. See for instance References [1](https://doi.org/10.1080/10426500108546530) and [[2]](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja0004175).

[image]

Structure of a lithium cyclobutadienide complex, from Ref. [2]. Unlabeled atoms in the ring substituents and solvent molecules are carbon; hydrogen atoms are not shown.

**References**

1. Akira Sekiguchi, Tsukasa Matsuo & Hidetoshi Watanabe (2001). "Cyclobutadiene Dianion Dilithium: a New Aromatic Ring System**. *Phosphorus, Sulfur, and Silicon and the Related Elements* **168**:1, 51-58, https://doi.org/10.1080/10426500108546530.
2. Akira Sekiguchi, Tsukasa Matsuo, and Hidetoshi Watanabe (2000). "Synthesis and Characterization of a Cyclobutadiene Dianion Dilithium Salt:  Evidence for Aromaticity". *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **122**, 23, 5652–5653.
   https://doi.org/10.1021/ja0004175